# Convert string "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" to Local date

Tags: java, java-11

I have:

```java
String s = "2023-12-15T10:13:44.544Z'
```

I would like to extract date part alone using Java 11. What are all best approaches we can use Java 11 to get date(yyyy-MM-dd) alone?
I appreciate your help!

Comment: something like `ZonedDateTime.parse("2023-12-15T10:13:44.544Z").toLocalDate()` ?

Comment: Or something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998063/how-can-i-make-a-datetimeformatter-that-accepts-trailing-junk

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

```
Instant
.parse( "2023-12-15T10:13:44.544Z" )
.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )
.toLocalDate()
.toString()
```

Or:

```
"2023-12-15T10:13:44.544Z".substring( 0 , 10 )
```

[Run both at Ideone.com.](https://ideone.com/BSCnsm)

> 2023-12-15

### *java.time*

Use the *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) for all your date-time work.

The `Z` on the end of your input string indicates an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Parse as an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2023-12-15T10:13:44.544Z" ) ;
```

Convert to the more flexible [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Extract the date only portion as a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Generate text is ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DD.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

### String manipulation

Or more simply, just [chop off](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) the rest of the text after the date portion.

```
String output = "2023-12-15T10:13:44.544Z".substring( 0 , 10 ) ;
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/BSCnsm).